# I can't publish a App Engine application to GCloud using the Google Cloud Platform tools in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-app-engine, gcloud

I just moved my application to use ASP.Net on .Net Core 3.1. I previously was using NodeJS and Express. I installed the Google Cloud Platform tools for Visual Studio, generated the app.yaml and Dockerfile using the right click menu on my project, modified the app.yaml to what I would assume is a valid configuration, and attempted to publish it. I selected App Engine Flex, selected my project, and I got a "The selected GCP project needs services to be enabled before you can deploy. Enable the services" message. Clicking on Enable the services (which looks like a link) does not do anything. This is preventing be from publishing my app, which is kind of annoying.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

app.yaml

```
service: api
runtime: custom
env: flex
env_variables:
    ASPNETCORE_ENVIROMENT: "production"
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
    min_idle_instances: 0
    max_idle_instances: 2
    min_pending_latency: 15ms
    max_pending_latency: 100ms
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore:3.1
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project Phoenix Game Services.dll"]
```

Comment: Can you please verify that [all of the prerequisites here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart) are met?

Comment: Double checking everything. May take a while to make sure everything is setup correctly, so I will comment again when I am done.

Comment: I ensured that the SDK was up to date, Visual Studio 2019 was fully up to date, the extension was up to date, that I had the .Net Core 2 and 3 LTS installed, and that App Engine was setup (it was, it is currently running a NodeJS application). I am running out of ideas. @EmilGi

Comment: Can't help you much here unfortunately, maybe this is a UI issue, maybe you can get the link itself from the button and try to go there manually. Otherwise try other support channels described [here](https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/getting-support).

Comment: @EmilGi do you have any update?

Answer (score 6):

Enable the App Engine Admin API.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me also, when trying to publish a .NET 6 Web API. In order to solve it this is what I did:

1. Went to my dashboard https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. Searched for "App Engine Admin API", using the search bar on the top
3. Enabled it.